# Conditional Probability but not Conditional Probability?

Tags: solution-verification, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

> Coin A is a fair coin and coin B is weighted so that the probability of obtaining heads is 0.6.  An experiment consists of randomly choosing a [single, fixed] coin and then flipping it 10 times.  Given that the coin came up heads exactly 6 times in the 10 flips, what is the probability that you selected the weighted coin?

For each coin this is a pint binomial probability, not cumulative.
For the fair coin, p=0.5, q=0.5, x= 6, n = 10, and I get P( 6 tosses ) = 0.20508 $\approx 0.205$,  A = choose fair coin.
For the biased coin, p=0.6, q=0.4, x= 6, n = 10, and I get P( 6 tosses ) = 0.25082 $\approx 0.251$, B = choose biased coin

> Method A. However, for P( I chose biased coin ), it reads like a conditional probability.
> $$ P( B|A) = \frac{P(\space A\space and\space B\space)}{P(\space B \space)}$$
> But the numerator for conditional probability is P ( fair and biased) = 0.  You can't chose both coins- fair and biased.  So obviously, this is incorrect.
> Method B. So I worked it this way-
> $$ P( chose\space biased\space coin) = \frac{0.251}{0.251 + 0.205}\approx 0.5504$$
> Is this correct?
> Please clarify and elaborate on the distinctions between the two methods.

Source:  I'm a tutor and this came from a student's worksheet.

Comment: Your second method is correct, and equivalent to what Bayes' Theorem would say.  I don't understand your first method.

Comment: How would you get the 2nd method from Bayes Thm.?  Bayes relies upon knowing at least one of P(B|A) or P(A|B), and I don't know either.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $A,B$.  If, say, $A$ is the event "you drew the biased coin".  and $B$ is the event "you observed six $H's$ out of  ten.". Then Bayes would have you write $P(A|B)=P(B|A)\times P(A)/ P(B)=.5\times .251/(.5\times .251+.5\times .205)$ which is equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: To prevent confusion especially for other readers, we used A & B to mean different things.
Also, your P(B|A)×P(A)/P(B)=.5×.251/ ( ... )  switched the order, and confused me at first.  P(A) = 0.5  not P(A) = 0.251

Comment: You never defined your notation. I did define mine, so let's stick with mine.

Comment: You're the 2nd person to suggest I did not define my notation.  I'm assuming you mean A or B.  Are these definitions not visible, technical glitch?
A = choose fair coin.
B = choose biased coin
I edited the question to include these definitions, 3.5 hours ago.

Comment: Ok...but those definitions aren't appropriate for the problem.  Obviously if you choose one coin then you can't have chosen the other.  But so what?  That has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly defining the events of interest and using proper terminology and notation is important for communicating mathematics and arriving at a clear answer.  At no point do you define what you mean by "A" and "B."  You don't define what your variables represent.  You don't state your assumptions and the model.  This sort of "computation without explanation" is perplexingly common among students and is, in my opinion, a symptom of an answer-focused approach to doing math, as opposed to process-focused.

Here is how the reasoning might proceed.  Let $A$ be the event that the fair coin is selected, and $B$ be the complementary event that the biased coin is selected.  Let $n = 10$ be the number of flips of whichever coin is selected.  If event $A$ occurs, then $p = 0.5$ is the probability that the coin lands heads.  If event $B$ occurs, then $p = 0.6$ is the probability that the coin lands heads.  Let $X$ be a random variable that counts the number of heads obtained in $n = 10$ flips.  Then we model the number of heads observed with a binomial distribution conditional on which coin was selected, i.e. $$\begin{align}X \mid A &\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 10, p = 0.5) \\ X \mid B &\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 10, p = 0.6). \end{align}\tag{1}$$

With this notation established, we are asked for $$\Pr[B \mid X = 6],$$ the posterior conditional probability that, given we observed $X = 6$ heads, that event $B$ occurred--i.e., we selected the biased coin.  Now we are ready to proceed with the computation, via Bayes' rule:

$$\Pr[B \mid X = 6] = \frac{\Pr[X = 6 \mid B]\Pr[B]}{\Pr[X = 6]}. \tag{2}$$  The denominator, which is the unconditional or marginal probability of obtaining $6$ heads, is calculated from the law of total probability, in which we condition on which coin was selected:

$$\Pr[X = 6] = \Pr[X = 6 \mid A]\Pr[A] + \Pr[X = 6 \mid B]\Pr[B]. \tag{3}$$  Note that $A$ and $B$ are complementary events that encompass the entire set of outcomes for the coin selection process.

From $(1)$, we can readily calculate the conditional probabilities

$$\begin{align}\Pr[X = 6 \mid A] &= \binom{10}{6} (1/2)^{6} (1 - 1/2)^{10 - 6} = \frac{105}{512} \approx 0.205078, \\ \Pr[X = 6 \mid B] &= \binom{10}{6} (6/10)^{6} (1 - 6/10)^{10 - 6} = \frac{489888}{1953125} \approx 0.250823. \end{align}\tag{4}$$

As for $\Pr[A]$ and $\Pr[B]$, the question strongly implies but does not explicitly state that the coin selection is equiprobable--we are told the coin is chosen "at random" which suggests that $$\Pr[A] = \Pr[B] = \frac{1}{2}, \tag{5}$$ which means that either coin is equally likely to be chosen than the other.  In such a case, the posterior probability simplifies to $$\Pr[B \mid X = 6] = \frac{\Pr[X = 6 \mid B]}{\Pr[X = 6 \mid A] + \Pr[X = 6 \mid B]} \approx \frac{0.250823}{0.205078 + 0.250823} \approx 0.550169.$$

The exact value is $$\Pr[B \mid X = 6] = \frac{\frac{3^6 \cdot 2^4}{5^{10}}}{\frac{1}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^6 \cdot 2^4}{5^{10}}} = \frac{3^6 \cdot 2^{14}}{5^{10} + 3^6 \cdot 2^{14}} = \frac{11943936}{21709561}.$$

---

Regarding your "Method A," it I have no idea what you are trying to say, because you did not define the events of interest.  If I interpret $A$ and $B$ as I have done in my solution (i.e. they are events that correspond to the choice of coin), then the statement $\Pr[B \mid A]$ means "the probability that coin $B$ was selected, given that coin $A$ was selected."  Obviously, that is $0$, and the formula says as much.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your extensive answer.

With all due respect, I edited it 3 hours to include this "A=choose fair coin "  and "B=choose biased coin".  However, your answer suggesting I did not define A or B was posted 1 hour ago.  Ummmm, would reading updates before answering simplify things?

Comment: @nickalh The reason why multiple people, including myself, have said you did not define your notation, is because what you wrote is not consistent with itself and is unclear; therefore we can't determine whether you actually defined the events in question, or if you did define it but then failed to apply those definitions correctly.  As I have already pointed out, even if you did define $A$ and $B$ as I had, you then inexplicably proceed to write $\Pr[B \mid A]$.  You then also write "choose biased coin" when you supposedly defined $B$ to represent this event.

Comment: @nickalh Another problem with the presentation of your work is that definitions generally come first.  You seem to treat them as an afterthought, or you omit their correct use.  For instance, you write "P(6 tosses) = 0.20508" and then after that, write "A = choose fair coin."  Ignoring the fact you mean "heads" instead of "tosses", this is not clearly expressed because this is a conditional probability, i.e. "P(6 heads | A) = 0.20508, where A is the event that the fair coin was chosen."  Otherwise, "P(6 heads)" is the unconditional probability of getting 6 heads.

Answer (score 1):

> But the numerator for conditional probability is P ( fair and biased) = 0.  You can't chose both coins- fair and biased.  So obviously, this is incorrect.

The correct numerator is $~\mathsf P(\text{result and biased})~$.

Thus we have method B:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\text{biased}\mid\text{result})&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(\text{result and biased})}{\mathsf P(\text{result and biased})+\mathsf P(\text{result and unbiased})}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{0.251\cdot 0.5}{0.251\cdot 0.5+0.205\cdot 0.5}\end{align}$$